# Differentiate Choices with Correct Answer using PHP

Tags: php, css, radio-button

there will be 4 options
option1,option2,option3,option4

```
(A) Any student who does not have the power to learn in a group is almost always unsuccessful 

(B) EDPeer group pressure and mutual understanding of any concept develops better understanding among students 

(C) ESAny student who does not have the power to learn in a group is almost always unsuccessful 

(D) Peer group pressure and mutual understanding of any concept develops better understanding among students
```

> $single_answer1="ESAny student who does not have the power to learn in
>   a group is almost always unsuccessful ".

**$single_answer1 is the answer choosen by student.**

*From the above choices "option1" is right answer but student choose "option3".*

I have to differentiate like for
"option1" with background green
"option3" with background color red

if sometimes option1 and answer both are equal then give border color green.

If single_answer is "undefined" or empty value then it will show correct answer with yellow background(not selected anythng & correct answer).

```
<?php if ($option1 == $single_answer1) { ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($single_answer1 != $option1) {
    ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($single_answer1 == 'undefined') { ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else { ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px">
        <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option1; ?>" ></span> (A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } ?><br/><br/>
```

I tried like this but I'm getting wrong output please anyone help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your shuffling logic,

```
$a = [$option1, $option2, $option3, $option4];
shuffle($a);
$b      = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4'];
$result = array_combine($b, $a);
extract($result);
```

Here is your code,

```
if ($option1 == $correct_answer && $correct_answer == $single_answer1) {
    $sc_flag = 1; // student's selected correct flag
}
if ($option2 == $correct_answer && $correct_answer == $single_answer1) {
    $sc_flag = 2;
}
if ($option3 == $correct_answer && $correct_answer == $single_answer1) {
    $sc_flag = 3;
}
if ($option4 == $correct_answer && $correct_answer == $single_answer1) {
    $sc_flag = 4;
}
if ($option1 == $correct_answer) {
    $correct_flag = 1; // correct answer
}
if ($option2 == $correct_answer) {
    $correct_flag = 2;
}
if ($option3 == $correct_answer) {
    $correct_flag = 3;
}
if ($option4 == $correct_answer) {
    $correct_flag = 4;
}
if ($option1 == $single_answer1) {
    $actual_flag = 1; // selected option by student
}
if ($option2 == $single_answer1) {
    $actual_flag = 2;
}
if ($option3 == $single_answer1) {
    $actual_flag = 3;
}
if ($option4 == $single_answer1) {
    $actual_flag = 4;
}
?>
<?php if ($sc_flag == 1) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($actual_flag == 1 && $correct_flag != 1) {
    ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($correct_flag == 1) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid yellow;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:yellow;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px">
        <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option1; ?>" ></span> (A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
    </label>
<?php }?><br/><br/>
<?php if ($sc_flag == 2) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(B) <?php echo $option2; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($actual_flag == 2 && $correct_flag != 2) {
    ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(B) <?php echo $option2; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($correct_flag == 2) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid yellow;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:yellow;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(B) <?php echo $option2; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px">
        <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option2; ?>" ></span> (B) <?php echo $option2; ?>
    </label>
<?php }?><br/><br/>
<?php if ($sc_flag == 3) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(C) <?php echo $option3; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($actual_flag == 3 && $correct_flag != 3) {
    ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(C) <?php echo $option3; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($correct_flag == 3) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(C) <?php echo $option3; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px">
        <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option3; ?>" ></span> (C) <?php echo $option3; ?>
    </label>
<?php }?><br/><br/>
<?php if ($sc_flag == 4) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(D) <?php echo $option4; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($actual_flag == 4 && $correct_flag != 4) {
    ?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(D) <?php echo $option4; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else if ($correct_flag == 4) {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
        <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
        <span class="">(D) <?php echo $option4; ?>
    </label>
<?php } else {?>
    <label style="font-size:14px">
        <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option4; ?>" ></span> (D) <?php echo $option4; ?>
    </label>
<?php }?><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $rightAnswer = $option1; // get right answer from db?>
<?php if($rightAnswer == $option1): ?>    
<?php if ($option1 == $single_answer1) { ?>
<label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
    <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
    <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
</label>
<?php } else if ($single_answer1 != $option1) {
?>
<label style="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px" >
    <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></i></label>
    <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
</label>
<?php } else if ($single_answer1 == 'undefined' || empty($single_answer1)) { ?>
<label style="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid green;padding:10px" >
    <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
    <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
</label>
<?php } ?>
<?php else: ?>
<label style="font-size:14px">
    <span class=""><input type="radio" name="single_question_answer1" value="<?php echo $option1; ?>" ></span> (A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
</label>
<?php endif; ?><br/><br/>
```

Hope this helps.
Updated:
I have created a function to get the right class/css

```
<?php
 //function to get option class
 //$rightOption - right answer
 //$currentOption - option name like option1 / option2 / option3 / option4
function getOptionClass($rightOption, $currentOption, $selectedOption=''){
    if(empty($selectedOption) && $rightOption == $currentOption){
    $optionClass = 'yelloClass'; //write style for this class in your css file 
    }elseif($currentOption == $rightOption && $currentOption == $selectedOption){
    $optionClass = 'greenClass';
    }elseif($currentOption == $selectedOption && $currentOption != $rightOption){
    $optionClass = 'redClass';
    }else{
    $optionClass = ''; // or assign your default class
    }
  return $optionClass;
 }
 ?>
 //for $option1
 $option_class = getOptionClass($rightOption, $option1, $selectedOption); //
 <label style="<?php echo $option_class; ?>" >
     <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
     <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
 </label>
 //for $option2
 $option_class = getOptionClass($rightOption, $option2, $selectedOption); //
 <label style="<?php echo $option_class; ?>" >
    <label class="review-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green;font-size:15px"></i></label>
    <span class="">(A) <?php echo $option1; ?>
 </label>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: We need to compare with all other options. So that We can differentiate selected & correct answer.Not selected& correct answer. Selected and wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to get the concept

```
        <?php 

        if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
            $option1 =$_POST['answer'];
        }else{
            $option1 ='undefined';
        }
        $single_answer1 ='c';

        ?>
        <?php if($option1 == $single_answer1) {
            $outer_label_style ="font-size:14px;background-color:green;border:1px solid green;padding:10px";    
            $inner_i_class ="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o";
            $inner_label_style ="color:green;font-size:15px";
        } else if($option1 <> 'undefined' && $single_answer1!=$option1) {               
            $outer_label_style ="font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px";  
            $inner_i_class ="fa fa-fw fa-times";
            $inner_label_style ="color:red;font-size:15px";
        } else if($option1 =='undefined') {         
            $outer_label_style ="font-size:14px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid green;padding:10px";   
            $inner_i_class ="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o";
            $inner_label_style ="color:green;font-size:15px";
         } else { 
            $outer_label_style ="font-size:14px";   
            $inner_i_class ="";
            $inner_label_style ="";
        } ?>

        <br/><br/>

         <?php 

             $style['a']['outer_label_style'] = "";
             $style['a']['inner_i_class'] = "";
             $style['a']['inner_label_style'] = "";   

             $style['b']['outer_label_style'] = "";
             $style['b']['inner_i_class'] = "";
             $style['b']['inner_label_style'] = "";

             $style['c']['outer_label_style'] = "";
             $style['c']['inner_i_class'] = "";
             $style['c']['inner_label_style'] = "";

             $style['d']['outer_label_style'] = "";
             $style['d']['inner_i_class'] = "";
             $style['d']['inner_label_style'] = "";



         if($single_answer1 == 'a'){
             $style['a']['outer_label_style'] = $outer_label_style;
             $style['a']['inner_i_class']     = $inner_i_class;
             $style['a']['inner_label_style'] = $inner_label_style;

         }elseif($single_answer1 == 'b'){
             $style['b']['outer_label_style'] = $outer_label_style;
             $style['b']['inner_i_class']     = $inner_i_class;
             $style['b']['inner_label_style'] = $inner_label_style;
         }elseif($single_answer1 == 'c'){
             $style['c']['outer_label_style'] = $outer_label_style;
             $style['c']['inner_i_class']     = $inner_i_class;
             $style['c']['inner_label_style'] = $inner_label_style;
         }elseif($single_answer1 == 'd'){
             $style['d']['outer_label_style'] = $outer_label_style;
             $style['d']['inner_i_class']     = $inner_i_class;
             $style['d']['inner_label_style'] = $inner_label_style;
         }

         if($option1 <> 'undefined' && $single_answer1!=$option1){       

             $style[$single_answer1]['outer_label_style'] = "font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid green;padding:10px";
             $style[$single_answer1]['inner_i_class']     = "fa fa-fw fa-times";
             $style[$single_answer1]['inner_label_style'] = "color:red;font-size:15px";

             $style[$option1]['outer_label_style'] = "font-size:14px;background-color:lightgray;border:1px solid red;padding:10px";
             $style[$option1]['inner_i_class']     = "fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o";
             $style[$option1]['inner_label_style'] = "color:green;font-size:15px";

            }
         ?>       


        <form method='post'>
         <label style="<?php echo $style['a']['outer_label_style'];?>" >
            <label class="review-icon"><i class="<?php echo $style['a']['inner_i_class'];?>" style="<?php echo $style['a']['inner_label_style'];?>"></i></label>            
            (A) <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a" <?php echo (isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] =='a')?'checked':'';?> > A) Any student who does not have the power to learn in a group is almost always unsuccessful<br>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <label style="<?php echo $style['b']['outer_label_style'];?>" >
            <label class="review-icon"><i class="<?php echo $style['b']['inner_i_class'];?>" style="<?php echo $style['b']['inner_label_style'];?>"></i></label>            
            (<input type="radio" name="answer" value="b" <?php echo (isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] =='b')?'checked':'';?>> (B) EDPeer group pressure and mutual understanding of any concept develops better understanding among students<br>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <label style="<?php echo $style['c']['outer_label_style'];?>" >
            <label class="review-icon"><i class="<?php echo $style['c']['inner_i_class'];?>" style="<?php echo $style['c']['inner_label_style'];?>"></i></label>            
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="c" <?php echo (isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] =='c')?'checked':'';?>> (C) ESAny student who does not have the power to learn in a group is almost always unsuccessful <br>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <label style="<?php echo $style['d']['outer_label_style'];?>" >
            <label class="review-icon"><i class="<?php echo $style['d']['inner_i_class'];?>" style="<?php echo $style['d']['inner_label_style'];?>"></i></label>            
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="d" <?php echo (isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] =='d')?'checked':'';?>> (D) Peer group pressure and mutual understanding of any concept develops better understanding among students <br>
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
         <button type="submit">Submit </button>
        </form>
```